# Can ExePackage update Bundle variable value at runtime

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I have written a managed bootstrapper application using WiX toolset's burn API and it works great. Currently it chains 2 MSI packages. Now I need to chain a exe package before the 2 MSIs. This exe package will obtain a value (when it runs) which it needs to pass back to the bootstrapper. Basically, the bootstrapper has a bunch of variables which it uses to populate properties in the 2 MSIs. One of these variables now needs to be updated by the exe package at runtime, so the corresponding MSI property reflects the correct value.

I have looked around and not been able to find anything that indicates that this can even be done. These two links ([here](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg35587.html) and [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Burn-Variables-td7463297.html)) speak of similar things, but they all mention that burn variables can be updated at runtime via command-line or within the bootstrapper itself. Not how a ExePackage could pipe back an update to a bundle variable, which is what I need to do.

Would appreciate any feedback.

**[UPDATE]**

Found a comment by the WiX developer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950718/wix-bootstrapper#comment21575911_15115564) that points to some sort of communication mechanism between an ExePackage and the bootstrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no mechanism to let a package communicate with the Burn engine, other than to indicate success or failure.